# How can I connect and retrieve data from a Firebird database in Java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I've installed an external desktop application and established connection with their example Firebird database (it is locally on my computer, I have all parameters, passwords).

How can I connect to that Firebird database in my own application written in Java using `.FDB` file?

Do I have to establish new connection and build new database or directly connect?

Comment: This question is too broad and unspecific, exactly what are you having problems with? For connecting to a Firebird database using Jaybird, look at the [Jaybird 2.1 Programmers manual](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/Jaybird_2_1_JDBC_driver_manual.pdf) or https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Connect-with-DriverManager